# what are the scenarios where System object might throw a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am preparing for an interview and while I was going through null pointer exceptions, I suddenly realized every object is somehow capable of throwing a null pointer exception, but I can't seem to imagine certain objects like System, Out etc. throwing `NullPointerException`. 
Can anyone mention such scenarios? Thank you!

For example: `System.out.println(s.get(name));`

Comment: Not *every* object is capable of throwing an NPE. You could trivially write one that does not.

Comment: if your example throws NPE, it was thrown by `s', not System.

Comment: What led you to this "realization" anyhow?

Comment: `System` isn't an instance (object), it's a class. `System.out` is a static field of the class and _is_ an instance of `PrintStream`.

Comment: @slim :  can you mention why and how certain objects cant be throwing npe?

Comment: @ekbaaraaja write a class with one method -- `public int getOne() { return 1; }`. There is nothing you can do to an object of that class that will cause an NPE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, `System` is not an object. It is a class whose methods are static. Second, `out` is a static field of that class that is (initially) a reference to a standard output `PrintStream`. You can change that `PrintStream` to your own with `System.setOut(PrintStream)`.

Finally, if you did

```
System.setOut(null);
System.out.println("42"); // because out is now a null reference
```

you would get a `NullPointerException`.

Sure, you can find a method of `System` that throws a `NullPointerException` as well.

Most of these `NullPointerException` are thrown by the JVM when you try to dereference a `null` object reference.

You don't dereference a class.

> Only executable code can throw an NPE, such as a method, constructor,
>   or an initializer. [- Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384033/what-are-the-scenarios-where-system-object-might-throw-a-null-pointer-exception/18384184?noredirect=1#comment26999541_18384184)

Comment: +1 for writing a right answer while I was posting a wrong one :)

Comment: ... although even here, it's not `System` that's throwing the NPE. Whatever method contains this code throws the NPE, because it's trying to make a method call on `null`.

Comment: @slim You can also try calling `out.write(null)`. The method expects a `byte[]`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in that case it is not System that is throwing the NPE. It is the OutputStream System.out.

Comment: @slim Right. It's impossible for a static class reference to cause NPE.

Comment: It is no less possible for an *object* to cause NPE, because neither class nor object is executable code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I meant that as in you don't dereference a class.

Comment: But there's a direct parallel between `System.getProperty(null)` throwing an NPE and `out.write(null)` throwing it. If the latter one is described as an object throwing it, then the former must be described as the class throwing it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sure, `System` class methods can throw NPE. `OutputStream` methods can throw NPE. But what is causing the NPE is the act of dereferencing (or a `null` check`. That's what I'm try to get at.

Comment: It is quite clear what you are getting at, and the only way to state it is "only executable code can throw an NPE, such as a method, constructor, or an initializer". The act of dereferencing `null` would be one of the ways the exception can be thrown.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That is implied. But I'll add it up there.

Comment: Very meticulous of you :) But seriously, beginners are likely to confuse just such elementary things because they don't have all the concepts clearly delineated. I don't think this is just an exercise in nitpicking.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I try to use as many relevant keywords as I can in my answers. We obviously can't cover everything in a single answer.

Comment: I just joined in the discussion below the answer. If I was a beginner reading the other comments, they would confuse the hell out of me. So I felt the urge to chime in, that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

Not every object is capable of throwing a NullPointerException. It's generally best to try to write classes that cannot!

```
public class ClassThatCannotNPE {

     public int getOne() {
         return 1;
     }
}
```

The only two things you can do with the above class, are to run its constructor, and invoke getOne(). Neither of those things can NPE.

We must be careful to define what we mean by saying that "something" throws an exception. This code will throw an NPE at line 2:

```
Date d = null;
System.setProperty("now",d.toString());
```

But that's not an example of System, or code from System, throwing the exception. The code above is equivalent to:

```
Date d = null;
String temp = d.toString();
System.setProperty(temp);
```

This would also throw an NPE at line 2 -- before System.setProperty() gets a chance to run. The execution order is exactly the same as the previous example.

What about:

```
System.out.print(null);
```

This will throw an NPE. But once again, it's not code from System that's throwing it. It is equivalent to:

```
PrintStream temp = System.out;
temp.print(null);
```

The NPE happens at line 2 -- which doesn't refer to System nor anything that refers to System.

---

`System` is a class, not an object. It does not have a constructor, so cannot be instantiated.

However, it has a lot of static methods. Is it possible to make any of those throw a NullPointerException?

Actually, we can find out pretty quickly by looking at the [Javadoc for System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html), and searching for "NullPointerException". The first match of many is in [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

> If dest is null, then a NullPointerException is thrown.

So there you have it:

```
System.arrayCopy(null,0,null,0,0);
```

... will cause some of the code in the System class to throw an NPE.

---

In fact we can look at the [actual source code for System](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/System.java.html) and see where it throws NullPointerExceptions.

```
488       public static native void arraycopy(Object src,  int  srcPos,
489                                           Object dest, int destPos,
490                                           int length);
```

Oh. arraycopy is native - meaning the actual implementation is some C code in the JRE. But what else can we find?

```
825       private static void checkKey(String key) {
826           if (key == null) {
827               throw new NullPointerException("key can't be null");
828           }
...
```

and

```
777       public static String setProperty(String key, String value) {
778           checkKey(key);
...
```

So another way to make code from System throw an NPE is:

```
System.setProperty(null,"value");
```

Answer (score 0):

An operation on a `null` object will throw a `NullPointerException`.  In the example `s.get(name)` e if `s` is `null` then a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.  Since `System` is an `class`, a static reference will not be null.  Looking at the source you can see that `out` is static and `final` and is eventually initialized with the following command.

```
setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));
```

Normally since it is `final` this means that it will not be `null` and cannot be made `null`.  However `public static void setOut(PrintStream out)` calls a native function `private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out)` in which the implementing VM can create a null reference.

It depends on the implementation of a method whether or not it will throw a `NullPointerException`.  Specifically `println(String)` will do a null check before operating on the passed in variable.

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
    }
```

So in that case the method itself should not throw a `NullPointerException` as long as the `PrintStream` is properly initialized which in the case of `System` it is.

I hope that helps answer your question.  If not, please articulate in the comments what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper class are capable of throwing NPE.Although java provides autoboxing,but they are not initialized by default unlike primitive data type.

```
Integer r;
if(r>1)
```