# JavaFX - FXML: initialize() does not seem to recognize instance variables

Tags: initialization, javafx-8, instance-variables

A request for an explanation.
If the explanation is elsewhere on the web, I could not find it.
The issue seems like it applies to all kinds of FXML custom widgets.

This is a considerable simplification of a working program module.
The original thought was to initialize and use some instance variables
 in the custom widget Controller.

When the variable initialization was done in the Constructor, all worked well.
The idea of moving the initialization from the Constructor
 to an "initialize()" method seemed good at the time.
Mainly, in case the future might hold more variables that are not ready until
 after the Constructor has run.

Using the "initialize()" method surfaced something I do not fully understand
 as exemplified by the code here.

The "initialize()" method does not seem to recognize instance variables.
The code provided is in working form, that is widget appears and works.
That is bad stuff is commented out just so folks can see it works.

However, if one uncomments the "initialize()" method and attempts to run
 the program, it dies with a NullPointerException on a simple instance variable.
 The actual program failed to recognize a HashMap but the PrintStream here
 makes for less clutter in the posted code.

The problem occurs with or without @FXML annotations in all kinds of places
 and combinations.

There seem to be various possible reasons for the failure, maybe including the following.
1. "initialize()" does not work the way I think it does after reading its description.
2. "initialize()" and process Threads are not talking to each other?
3. The custom widget controller deriving from a super class messes things up?
4. The tests were run inside NetBeans 8.0.2 with Java 8 and that messes it up? But then the question becomes why?
5. Annotations do not work well with sub-classing?
6. Combinations of the above or something entirely different?

*The custom controller Java code, DirectorySelectionWidgets.java:*

```
package blogpost ;

// Java imports
import java.io  .PrintStream ;

// JavaFX imports
import javafx.event           .ActionEvent ;
import javafx.scene.control   .Button      ;
import javafx.scene.control   .Control     ;
import javafx.fxml            .FXML        ;

public class DirectorySelectionWidgets extends UserControl
  {
    @FXML
    private Button fromRootSelectionButton ;

    /**
     *  Does not work with or without @FXML annotation.
     */
//    @FXML
    protected PrintStream out = System.out ;

    /**
     *  UNCOMMENT method to see the NullPointerException on instance variable.
     *    The fuller version failed on important variables.
     *  <P>
     *  Does not work with or without @FXML annotation.
     */
//    @FXML
//    public void initialize()
//      { out.println( "HERE just entered initialize()" ) ; }

    public DirectorySelectionWidgets()
     { super() ; }

    @FXML
    private void handleRootSelectionRequest( ActionEvent actionEvent )
      {
        Control control = (Control) actionEvent.getSource() ;
        out.println( 
            "HERE control inside handleRootSelectionRequest control =>\n   "
            + control
                   ) ;
      }
  }
```

*The custom widget fxml file, DirectorySelectionWidgets.fxml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane id="rootSelectorPane" fx:id="rootSelectorPane" alignment="CENTER" gridLinesVisible="false" layoutY="42.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="828.0" styleClass="root-selector-pane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
  <children>
    <Button id="fromRootSelectionButton" fx:id="fromRootSelectionButton" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleRootSelectionRequest" prefWidth="168.0" styleClass="root-selector-buttons" text="Set 'From' Root Directory" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER" />
  </children>
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" halignment="LEFT" hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="166.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="-1.0" minHeight="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
  </rowConstraints>

<stylesheets>
  <URL value="@PuzzleCss.css" />
</stylesheets>
</GridPane>
```

*The custom widget super class, UserControl.java:*

```
package blogpost ;

/*
 *   Information link as of April 2016 is
 *   <A HREF="https://programmingwithpassion.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/creating-a-reusable-javafx-custom-control/">
 *     <I>Benjamin's programming Blog</I>.
 *   </A>
 * <BR>
 * Orginal copyright 2014 Benjamin Gale.
 * License document is also there inside the Java file on his blog.
 * <P>
 * Modified in accordance with license.
 */
// Java imports
import java.io            .IOException ;
import java.util.logging  .Level       ;
import java.util.logging  .Logger      ;
import java.net           .URL         ;

// JavaFX imports
import javafx.fxml          .FXMLLoader  ;
import javafx.geometry      .HPos        ;
import javafx.scene         .Node        ;
import javafx.scene.layout  .Region      ;
import javafx.geometry      .VPos        ;

/**
 *  This is a convenience class for creating custom controls that use the
 *    {@code FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader() ;}
 *    approach. Mainly used for custom widgets.
 *  <P>
 *  Just subclass this class and all the FXMLLoader work is already done.
 *  <P>
 *  The only file restrictions are the following.
 *    <UL>
 *      <LI>
 *        The controller file and the fxml file must be in the same package.
 *      </LI>
 *      <LI>
 *        The fxml file must have the same (case sensitive) name (sans suffix)
 *          as the controller class.
 *        <BR>
 *        That is, 
 *          if the controller file is named {@code MyController.java} then
 *          the fxml file must be named {@code MyController.fxml}.
 *          <BR>
 *          This also works with other JavaFX controller files; for example,
 *          {@code MyController.groovy} would work for Groovy developers.
 *      </LI>
 *    </UL>
 */
public abstract class UserControl extends Region
  {
    private final String resourcePath = "%s.fxml" ;

    public UserControl()
      { this.loadView() ; }

    /**
     *  A primary purpose for this class,
     *   make creating custom controls easier.
     */
    private void loadView()
      {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader() ;

        fxmlLoader.setController( this ) ;
        fxmlLoader.setLocation( this.getViewURL() ) ;

        try
          {
            Node root = (Node) fxmlLoader.load() ;
            setMaxSize( root ) ;

            this.getChildren().add( root ) ;
          }
        catch ( IOException ioException )
          { 
            Logger.getLogger( UserControl.class.getName() )
              .log( Level.SEVERE, null, ioException ) ;
          }
      }

    private String getViewPath()
      { return String.format( resourcePath, this.getClass().getSimpleName() ) ; }

    private URL getViewURL()
      { return this.getClass().getResource( this.getViewPath() ) ; }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren()
      {
        getChildren().stream().forEach(
            (node) ->
              { layoutInArea( node, 0, 0,
                              getWidth(), getHeight(),
                              0,
                              HPos.LEFT, VPos.TOP
                             ) ;
              }
          ) ;
      }

    private void setMaxSize(Node node)
      {
        if ( node != null && node instanceof Region )
          {
            Region region = (Region) node ;
            region.setMaxWidth(  Double.MAX_VALUE ) ;
            region.setMaxHeight( Double.MAX_VALUE ) ;
          }
      }
  }
```

*The Test Java code, DirectorySelectionWidgetsTest.java:*

```
package blogpost ;

// JavaFX imports
import javafx.application  .Application ;
import javafx.fxml         .FXMLLoader  ;
import javafx.scene        .Parent      ;
import javafx.scene        .Scene       ;
import javafx.stage        .Stage       ;

public class DirectorySelectionWidgetsTest extends Application
  {
    // Written this way while reducing code to smaller size and new locations.
    protected String fxmlFullFileName = ""
                   + "blogpost"
                   + "/"
                   + "DirectorySelectionWidgetsTest"
                   + "."
                   + "fxml" ;

    protected String mainTitle = "Test directory selection widgets" ;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage )
      throws Exception
      {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader() ;
          fxmlLoader.setController( this )       ;

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load( 
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( fxmlFullFileName )
                                     ) ;

        Scene scene = new Scene( root ) ;
          stage.setTitle( mainTitle )   ;
          stage.setScene( scene )       ;

        stage.show() ;
      }

    public static void main( String[] args )
      { launch( args ) ; }
  }
```

*The Test fxml file, DirectorySelectionWidgetsTest.fxml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import blogpost.*?>

<AnchorPane id="anchorPane" fx:id="anchorPane" styleClass="header-title-pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <DirectorySelectionWidgets id="selectionWidgets" fx:id="selectionWidgets" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@PuzzleCss.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

*The css file, PuzzleCss.css:*

```
.root-selector-buttons
  {
    -fx-background-color  :
      green, linear-gradient( to bottom right, #FFFF00 40%, #99FF33 100% ) ;
    -fx-text-fill : black ;
  }

.root-selector-pane
  {
    -fx-background-color  : #DDFFBB    ;
    -fx-border-color      : #DDFFBB    ;
  }

.rootSelectorTextFields
  {
    -fx-border-color : #00BB00 ;
    -fx-text-fill    : black   ;
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible you have [set System.out to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384033/what-are-the-scenarios-where-system-object-might-throw-a-null-pointer-exception)? Otherwise - please try to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sillyfly, fortunately, for my ego, that was not the issue. Except for the CSS file, the original code was the minimal I could use and still have the problem occur. The test program was needed to mimic using the custom widget in another FXML application, the super class, UserControl, interaction with the sub-class was the main issue. I tried to make it easy by having a short segment commented out. Your comment, really asked me why the sub-class instance variable was null when set-up had not finished. Error occurred before any instance variables were set in the sub-class. Answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is an unexpected start-up sequence.
I expected the usual constructor flow; super-class (UserControl) constructor -> sub-class (DirectorySelectionWidgets) constructor (define, sub-class variables, then run constructor code) -> etc.

What I got was the sub-class method, *initialize()* is called inside the super-class constructor operations prior to running the sub-class constructor.
Note: *initialize()* is a method inside the sub-class, DirectorySelectionWidgets.

Here is the trail.

DirectorySelectionWidgetsTest => start(), entered
UserControl() => Constructor, entered
DirectorySelectionWidgets.initialize() => initialize(), inside **UNEXPECTED CALL HERE**
UserControl() => Constructor, end
DirectorySelectionWidgets => Constructor, entered **EXPECTED *initialize()* CALL AFTER HERE**
DirectorySelectionWidgetsTest => start(), end

So the DirectorySelectionWidgets local variables are not defined at the time the sub-class method, *initialize()*, is run.

One speculation is, this is a consequence of the FXML infrastructure jumping to a sub-class *initialize()* method as soon as the top constructor in a sub-classing hierarchy is finished? The role of how the DirectorySelectionWidgetsTest *start()* method might contribute to this is unclear to me; a study for another time.

Any further insights would be most welcome but the unexpected start-up sequence certainly played a role in the puzzlement I had.